# Chebyshev interpolating polynomial theorem

Tags: interpolation, chebyshev-polynomials

Could anyone explain this Chebyshev interpolating polynomial theorem 3.5 ?

[image]

Comment: When you are interpolating a function, you can choose points either equidistant or in a different manner. When you deal with functions that change quickly, what happens is that equidistant points might cause your interpolation to blow up at certain points. Hence we want a way of selecting points that minimises the max error - which is how the chebyshev points are derived